# Ping broadcast on Win XP SP3

Tags: c++, networking, broadcast, ping

I'm trying to ping the broadcast address 255.255.255.255 on WinXP SP3.

If I use the command line, I get host error:

```
C:\>ping 255.255.255.255
Ping request could not find host 255.255.255.255. Please check the name and try again.
```

If I try a C++ program using the iphlpapi, `IcmpSendEcho()` fails and `GetLastError` returns 11010 `IP_REQ_TIMED_OUT`.

```
HANDLE h = ::IcmpCreateFile();
IPAddr broadcast = inet_addr( "255.255.255.255" );
BYTE payload[ 32 ] = { 0 };
IP_OPTION_INFORMATION option = { 255, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

// a buffer with room for 32 replies each containing the full payload
std::vector< BYTE > replies( 32 * ( sizeof( ICMP_ECHO_REPLY ) + 32 ) );

DWORD res = ::IcmpSendEcho( h, 
                            broadcast, 
                            payload, 
                            sizeof( payload ), 
                            &option, 
                            &replies[ 0 ], 
                            replies.size(), 
                            1000 );
::IcmpCloseHandle( h );
```

I can ping the local broadcast `192.168.0.255` with no problem.

What do I need to do to ping the global broadcast?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Let's hear what `ping ff02::1%0` will do... (may need to replace %0 by %1, %2, etc. to choose the interface.)

Comment: @user562374 - `Ping request could not find host ff02::1%X. Please check the name and try again.` For all values of X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work in Windows as I know. In Linux OS you can ping 255.255.255.255, but routing protocol will not relay 255.255.255.255 broadcasts outside of the local network.

What are you trying to achieve? Are you ready that every computer on the connected earth will respond? *I'm scared...*

---

By the way, you should be ready that no one will respond to the broadcast ping even in the local network. [This question on SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/110780/broadcast-ping-on-windows-lan) could be useful.

Comment: My goal is for every host on my network to respond regardless of the IP/Subnet they're configured for. Directed broadcast works fine. If they respond to directed broadcast wouldn't they respond to broadcast? Also, yes, this does work with my Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast UDP has been obsolete for about 20 years. It is most unlikely to get through a router to another subnet.

Comment: I'm not trying to ping the whole internet. I don't expect it to go through a router.

Comment: @PaulH: You're expecting it to go to multiple subnets. That means traversing routers or bridges or bridging hosts. You can't expect 255.255.255.255 to work for this purpose.

Comment: not necessarily. You can have multiple subnets on the same switch. It is not normally done that way. But it is possible to do.